# PyArrow/S3FileSystem: How to use the retry_strategy correctly with self defined max attempts

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, pyarrow

I'm using pyarrow.parquet to write parquet files to S3. We have high request rates and it was hitting the 3,500 requests limit per second per partitioned prefix so I was trying to have some retry logic in place.

Then I found there's a filesystem parameter in pyarrow.parquet.write_table function[1], and there's a S3FileSystem class [2][3] can be configured with a '**retry_strategy**' parameter. But I'm not 100% sure how to use this exactly, for example I would like to have a retry attempts of 10, can someone please help me to see if I'm doing the right thing? and if not what would be the correct way to use it? Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pyarrow import fs

# do something to prepare the data in a variable called `table` 

self_defined_retry = fs.AwsStandardS3RetryStrategy(max_attempts=10)  # I tried to just use the base class S3RetryStrategy but it gave me invalid error
s3_fs = fs.S3FileSystem(region='$region', retry_strategy=self_defined_retry)
pq.write_table(table, target_data_s3_path, filesystem=s3_fs)
```

I didn't receive any error from this but I'm not sure if it is really using the max attempts 10.

[1] https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html
[2] https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.S3FileSystem.html
[3] https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/python/pyarrow/_s3fs.pyx

Comment: Your code looks fine but I'll admit I've never encountered a situation where I triggered a retry. You might try calling `fs.initialize_s3(fs.S3LogLevel.Debug)` at the top of your script and inspecting the debug output to see whether retries are happening or not. While I have you, I'm looking into a way to reproduce hitting the 3,500 limit so any information about your setup would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @amoeba We have a DataSync job configured to sync files from another AWS account to our S3 bucket which will send messages to an SQS queue, the SQS queue will trigger the Lambda function to process the file. Every time that DataSync job runs, over ten thousands of files will be synced across and the Lambda function will be processing them at the same time, that's when it's hitting the 3,500 limits. Thank you for sharing any thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is correct. You can see an example of this usage within the unit tests:

https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/5c73973a23deb68bef75be8acd743763307ac12f/python/pyarrow/tests/test_fs.py#L1114-L1116

Comment: Thank you for sharing. However, when I use the logging suggested by @amoeba `fs.initialize_s3(fs.S3LogLevel.Debug)`, I saw the following debug output `[WARN] 2023-04-27 04:14:12.065 ClientConfiguration [53736] Retry Strategy will use the default max attempts.`  I'm wondering why it's saying will use the default max attempts. Am I missing anything? Thank you.